# Краш приложения с setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android, activity

Делаю две кнопки, для загрузки сохраненного текста и его сохранения.
в `OnCreate`:

```
 etText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etText); //поле для ввода
    btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave); //кнопка сохраненияя
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnLoad = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLoad); //кнопка загрузки
    btnLoad.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Дальше

```
    public void onClick(View v){
       switch (v.getId()){
           case R.id.btnSave:
               saveText();
               break;
           case R.id.btnLoad:
               loadText();
               break;
           default:
               break;
       }
   }

    private void saveText() {
        sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
        ed.putString(SAVED_TEXT, etText.getText().toString());
        ed.commit();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Text saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void loadText() {
        sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String savedText = sPref.getString(SAVED_TEXT,"");
        etText.setText(savedText);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Text loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

В итоге приложение завершается с ошибкой:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference at <имя пакета>.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:104)
        104 строка: btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Код разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLoad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Load">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
```

Comment: Можете добавить код разметки?

Comment: Добавил код разметки

Comment: На всякий случай спрошу, setContentView не забыли прописать?

Comment: Не забыл, прописан

Comment: Покажите больше кода onCreate(). И скажите, как называется файл с разметкой

Answer (score 1):

Переменная btnSave у вас, согласно ошибке, `null`

Это может произойти если вы

1. Опечатались в ID кнопки
2. Кнопки с таким ID вообще нет в используемой разметке
3. Вы пытаетесь искать кнопку в разметке до установки разметки через `setContentView()`
4. Ещё по ряду более сложных причин типа вложенных разметок с перекрытием ID

Comment: 1. все id правильные, 2. кнопки есть, 3. кнопки ищу до установки разметки, 4. перекрытий никаких нет

Comment: @АндрейУжегов как вы думаете, откуда там могут появится кнопки, если разметка ещё не установлена? Первым делом в методе ```onCreate``` в активити надо после вызова ```super.onCreate``` вызывать ```setContentView()``` во избежании таких вот ситуаций.

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); идет до установки кнопок

Comment: Т.е. теперь ищете после установки разметки и ничего не поменялось?

Comment: Ничего не поменялось, ошибка та же

Comment: Проверьте, что вы правильную разметку используете. И откючите InstantRun в студии, нсли оно включено

Answer (score 0):

Сделай Clear / Rebuild Project. Тогда заработает